# Is there a way I could simplify (make it easier on the eyes) the setting of a value using a switch expression and &&?

Tags: c#

Is there a way that I could simplify the setting of a value

```
 Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = devIsTablet && isLandscape ? new Thickness(150, 0, 150, 0) : devIsTablet && !isLandscape ? new Thickness(100, 0, 100, 0) : new Thickness(0);
```

I have used switch expressions but is it possible to use the && operator inside of those when choosing the case?

**Please note**. I am interested in all answers but if someone can tell me how to do it with a C# switch expression that would be my choice to accept that answer. I don't even mind if there are a few more characters there as my focus is on code readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you ask specifically to realize this with the `switch` expression, this would be how to do it:

```
Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = (devIsTablet, isLandscape) switch
{
    (true, true) => new Thickness(150, 0, 150, 0),
    (true, false) => new Thickness(100, 0, 100, 0),
    _ => new Thickness(0)
};
```

You use value tuples to switch on the different combinations. Whether this is more readable is of course subjective. You could opt for including the tuple element names in the switch cases as well:

```
Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = (devIsTablet, isLandscape) switch
{
    (devIsTablet: true, isLandscape: true) => new Thickness(150, 0, 150, 0),
    (devIsTablet: true, isLandscape: false) => new Thickness(100, 0, 100, 0),
    _ => new Thickness(0)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would write it out. I think the readability is worth the extra typing. If I wrote it your way I think my colleagues would hate me.

```
Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = ComputePageSideMarginThickness(devIsTablet, isLandscape);

Thickness ComputePageSideMarginThickness(bool devIsTablet, bool isLandscape)
{
    if (!devIsTablet) return new Thickness(0);
    var width = isLandscape ? 150 : 100;
    return new Thickness(100, 0, width, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm really hoping to find a solution that uses the switch expression if that's possible. Just not sure how to set up the case for those. Let's wait to see if anyone can come up with that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use if condition with ternary operator

```
//If you don't want to assign default value then, you can write this in else condition
Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(0); //Assign default value
if(devIsTablet)
{
   //Now you ternary operator
   var hightWidth = isLandscape ? 150 : 100;
   Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(hightWidth, 0, hightWidth, 0)

}
```

Comment: I'm really hoping to find a solution that uses the switch expression if that's possible. Just not sure how to set up the case for those. Let's wait to see if anyone can come up with that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its if-else form is as follows.

```
if(devIsTablet && isLandscape)
{
    Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(150, 0, 150, 0);
}
else if (devIsTablet /*&& !isLandscape*/)
{
    Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(100, 0, 100, 0);
}
else
{
    Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(0);
}
```

Even further in second `else-if` case `!isLandscape` is not necessary too.

Or if you wish, here is another version of it.

```
if (!devIsTablet || !isLandscape)
{
    if (devIsTablet)
    {
        Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(100, 0, 100, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(0);
    }
}
else
{
    Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(150, 0, 150, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm really hoping to find a solution that uses the switch expression if that's possible. Just not sure how to set up the case for those. Let's wait to see if anyone can come up with that as an answer.

Comment: @snr, we can using C#8 feature. look at other answers

Answer (score 0):

If using Ternary if conditions makes it too unreadable, then convert it to a normal if else/if block. It might take more space, but readable code is better than unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a decision matrix.
For example:

```
var discriminant = ( devIsTablet ? 2:0 ) + ( isLandscape? 1: 0 );
var thicknessParam = 0;
switch( discriminant )
{
    case 3:
    // device is tablet and tablet is in landscape mode
    thicknessParam = 150;
    break;
    case 2:
    // device is tablet and tablet is in portrait mode
    thicknessParam = 100;       
    break;  
    case 1:
    // device is not a tablet, but it is in landscape mode
    thicknessParam = 0;     
    break;  
    case 0:
    // device is not a tablet and it is in portrait mode
    thicknessParam = 0;             
    break;
    default:
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
var pageSideMargin = new Thickness( thicknessParam, 0, thicknessParam, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate for a switch expression, then something like the following should do the job (though I'm not sure it's more readable than the `if-else` form):

```
Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = (devIsTablet, isLandscape) switch  {
    (true, true) => new Thickness(150, 0, 150, 0),
    (true, false) => new Thickness(100, 0, 100, 0),
    _ => new Thickness(0)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could a mathematical approach if you want to caliber it depending on different sizes (either change 50, 2 and 1 and see result):

```
var a = 50 * ((devIsTablet ? 2 : 0) + (isLandscape ? 1 : 0));
Current.Resources["PageSideMargin"] = new Thickness(a, 0, a, 0);
```